# Issue with pytz DST

Tags: python, timezone-offset, pytz

I was trying to understand how pytz handles DST and following an example from the [documentation](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#problems-with-localtime), the pertinent parts of which are thus:

```
>>> fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z'
>>> eastern = timezone('US/Eastern')
>>> loc_dt = datetime(2002, 10, 27, 1, 30, 00)
>>> est_dt = eastern.localize(loc_dt, is_dst=True)
>>> edt_dt = eastern.localize(loc_dt, is_dst=False)
>>> print(est_dt.strftime(fmt) + ' / ' + edt_dt.strftime(fmt))
2002-10-27 01:30:00 EDT-0400 / 2002-10-27 01:30:00 EST-0500
```

Interestingly, repeating the example with `year=2020` produces two EDT dates with -0400 offsets:

```
>>> loc_dt = datetime(2020, 10, 27, 1, 30, 00)
>>> est_dt = eastern.localize(loc_dt, is_dst=True)
>>> edt_dt = eastern.localize(loc_dt, is_dst=False)
>>> print(est_dt.strftime(fmt) + ' / ' + edt_dt.strftime(fmt))
2020-10-27 01:30:00 EDT-0400 / 2020-10-27 01:30:00 EDT-0400
```

Why is there no EST date with an -0500 offset?

Comment: 10/27/2002 was the daylight saving transition day.  The transition day for 2020 was 11/1/2020.  I think `is_dst` only affects the time during the transition hour and is ignored otherwise.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I see that now. Thank you.